# How to give a permission to create log file in systemd service?

Tags: 20.04, services, log

Here is the line to start a process in systemd service and save log to `/var/log/besu`:

```
 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "$HOME/bin/besu/bin/besu --config-file=$HOME/bin/besu_network/node1/config.toml >> /var/log/besu/node1.log 2>&1"
```

However since the user does not have the write permission under `/var/log` and it throws error. How to give a `sudo` permission in the line above to create a log file, but not add the user to sudoer group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sudo a symbolic link into /var/log which points to a log file elsewhere that the user has write permission to.

OR

You could add the user to the `syslog` group so they then have write permission to `/var/log` Of course then that user could go end edit/delete other system logs but if it's you personally or a trusted user...

So for my `/var/log` I can see it's owner:group is `root:syslog`

So modify the user and add the syslog group:

`sudo usermod -a -G syslog <USERNAME_HERE>`

You will probably  have to logout/login for the change to take effect, not sure if there is a way to refresh users/groups dynamically.